# How can I use a MySql User Defined Variable in a .NET MySqlCommand?

Tags: .net, mysql, powershell

I simply want to execute the following Mysql statement

```
SET @a = 1;SELECT @a;
```

with  MySql.Data.MySqlClient

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")

$password = 'mypassword'

$sql = "SET @a = 1;SELECT @a;"

$server = 'localhost'
$port = 3306
$database = 'test'
$User = 'root'


$conn=new-object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$connectionstring =  "Server=$Server;Port=$port;Database=$DataBase;Uid=$User;Pwd=$Password;allow zero datetime=yes"
$conn.ConnectionString = $connectionstring 
$conn.Open() 

$cmd=new-object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($sql,$conn)
$ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet
$da=New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($cmd)
$da.fill($ds) 
$conn.close()
$ds.tables[0]
```

I get a fatal error.

When I replace $sql by either

```
$sql = "SELECT DATABASE();"
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT 1;"
```

I get the expected result.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958953/is-it-possible-to-use-a-mysql-user-defined-variable-in-a-net-mysqlcommand), but it doesn't solve my problem.

I'm trying to port SQLIse (a part of the [SQLPSX project](http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com/) ) to the MySQL version MySQLIse.

I want to process any simple valid mysql statements.

**EDIT:**

I was trying to run parts of the [sakila-schema.sql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila.html) the mysql demo database install script which runs by something like

> mysql> SOURCE
>   C:/temp/sakila-db/sakila-schema.sql;

Comment: does "SET @a = 1;SELECT @a;" work in standard MySql tool? In TSQL you need to declare the variable before you use it, "DECLARE @a int;SET @a = 1;SELECT @a;"

Comment: sakila-schema.sql starts with: SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I found the solution in this [blog](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2009/05/mysqldatamysqlclientmysqlexception-parameter-id-must-be-defined.html)

I have to add

```
;Allow User Variables=True
```

to the connection string:

```
$connectionstring = "Server=$Server;Port=$port;Database=$DataBase;Uid=$User;Pwd=$Password;allow zero datetime=yes;Allow User Variables=True"
```

works. I tested it with version 6.3.6.0. of `MySql.Data`.