# select from table with row number to c# datatable gives an error

Tags: c#, mysql, select, datatable

i use **MySQL**
i have a mysql table.
And i want to select all records with row numbers.
and for this i use this sql command.

```
SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row, t.* FROM t_persons t, (SELECT @row := 0) r
```

but when i try to run the command and load data to datatable like below

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
command.CommandText = sql;
adapter.SelectCommand = command;
adapter.Fill(dt);
```

it gives an error like **Fatal error encountered during command execution.**
But when i try this command in phpmyadmin it works fine. So what is the problem. And how to solve it.
  Thanks...

Comment: this doesn't look like sql to me.

Comment: @row look like parameters. Yet none are defined. This isnt how you build SQL in C#

Comment: I'm guessing `sql` is a string containing the query you showed earlier, right? But have you defined `@row` before using it?

Comment: no i did not define @row before...

Comment: The last part doesn't seem right to me: `, (SELECT @row := 0) r`. You should probably have to `set @row := 0;` and then append your `SELECT` query.

Comment: Uhm, seems to be right. [look here](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/156-MySQL-rownum-equivalent). The only difference is the `as`

Comment: but it runs in phpmyadmin.....

Comment: Your query works for me. The error must be something else!

Comment: how did you create the connection string in c#, could you add that part of your code to your question. might seem weird but had the same issue because signs like @ and others have a different meaning in c# and they might be interpreted instead of made part of your string.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a C# error, not a MySQL error. C# is seeing the @ and assuming that you want to use a parameterized query.

adding

`;Allow User Variables=True`

to your connection string will fix it.

Found here [How can I use a MySql User Defined Variable in a .NET MySqlCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524632/how-can-i-use-a-mysql-user-defined-variable-in-a-net-mysqlcommand)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like completely valid MySQL implementation of MySQL Variables within a query.  You pre-declare them with your select @row := 0 as an "r" alias.  It think the problem is that you are calling the final column name "row" which may be reserved.  Just for grins, change to:

@row := @row + 1 as myRow

OR... change your variable from @row to @varRow (variable Row)... or a combination of both...

@varRow := @varRow +1 as myRow

I have no idea who down-voted the answer, but what you are doing is quite normal with MySQL, and I've done it MANY TIMES as can be seen through MANY of my posted answers here at s/o.
I would then try to retrieve the columns by the table FIRST,  then the @vars columns... don't know if its something within the engine to get a valid record entry before trying to write the @var...

```
SELECT 
      t.*,
      @varRow := @varRow + 1 as myRow
   FROM 
      t_persons t, 
      (SELECT @varRow := 0) r
```

Comment: @namco, revised answer to try