# Passing parameters to MysqldataReder

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

```
SELECT machine_id,operator_id,member_id,card_id,name,paid_amount,due_amount,paid_date,phone_number,@curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM transaction JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
where card_id=@card
order by Row_number desc limit 3 ;
```

my query is giving correct results when i run in Mysql workbench. But in program it's giving error

> Parameter '@curRow' must be defined.

```
String query3 = "SELECT machine_id,operator_id,member_id,card_id,name,paid_amount,due_amount,paid_date,phone_number ,@curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number FROM transaction JOIN  (SELECT @curRow := 0) r where card_id=@card order by Row_number desc limit 3 ";

MySqlCommand command3 = new MySqlCommand(query3, con);
command3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@card", cardid);
using (MySqlDataReader rdr3 = command3.ExecuteReader())
```

Comment: post the relevant C# code please

Comment: Each parameter will match a `MySqlParameter` object that must be assigned to `MySqlCommand` object. But since you didn't show your code, we can't know exactly what the problem is..

Comment: This would *usually* be something like: 

    `int cardId = ...`
    `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("card", cardId);`

(repeat per parameter, also making sure that you use `DBNull.Value` and not `null` if you want to represent database-null); however! it varies a little between ADO.NET providers.

Comment: how to post my c# code

Comment: @user3260112 Select all your code with mouse. Right click the mouse and left click to `"Copy"` part, then come to your question. Click `"edit"` button under the question, there will be an area of your question. Right click there with mouse, then left click to `"Paste"` part.

Comment: plz any one help me , how to pass parameters.

Comment: The variable `@curRow` is a user defined variable in MySQL, the problem in your code is that Mysqlcommand treats it as a parameter, so it expects you to pass a variable to it, see [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958953/is-it-possible-to-use-a-mysql-user-defined-variable-in-a-net-mysqlcommand), it says that there was no way to solve it using the Mysql connect dot net.

Comment: Try to add `Allow User Variables=True` to the connection string, see this http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2009/05/mysqldatamysqlclientmysqlexception-parameter-id-must-be-defined.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use a MySql User Defined Variable in a .NET MySqlCommand?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524632/how-can-i-use-a-mysql-user-defined-variable-in-a-net-mysqlcommand)

Comment: but here am getting connection string from web.config how can i add Allow User Variables=True;