# Getting table name by position(row) from database

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get a table name by his position(row)? I got many tables.

For example in columns to find from a table it works this way:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database name here' 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'table name here' 
AND ORDINAL_POSITION = 2;
```

I need something like this only to find table name by their position(row) in the database.

Using MySQL. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve? Perhaps an example? It's a bit hard to understand the question.

Comment: For example getting the second/fifth table name in a database.

Comment: Why don't you just use `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1` to get the 2nd row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need something like that

```
SELECT position, TABLE_NAME
FROM (

  SELECT @row := @row +1 AS position, TABLE_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  JOIN (
   SELECT @row :=0
  )r
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =  'TABLE_SCHEMA here'
)tmp
WHERE position =5
```

and a different approach

```
SET @row =0;
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM (
   SELECT @row := @row +1 AS position, TABLE_NAME
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =  'TABLE_SCHEMA here'
)tmp
WHERE position =5
```

Comment: It works, but I only need the name of the table, I don't need position and name to be display (When I said position I meant using it in the WHERE).

Comment: you can select what ever you want 
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM (...)  WHERE position IN (1,5,6)

Comment: It works in MySQL, but when I try to print it in my website it say: Parameter '@row' must be defined.]

Comment: `DECLARE @row int;SET @row = 0;` 
if this doesn't work read about your problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524632/how-can-i-use-a-mysql-user-defined-variable-in-a-net-mysqlcommand)

Comment: @Naveh I am pleased you got an answer you are happy with!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want something like that:

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database name here' 
AND TABLE_NAME = (
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database name here'
    ORDER BY CREATE_TIME ASC
    LIMIT 1  -- take one
    OFFSET 1 -- after 1st row
)
```

This will return all colums from the table that was created as second table for that DB.