# simplifying non-parametrized mysql queries

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a problem with mySql query below

```
SELECT name, hospitalID, currentAvgRating, rank 
FROM ( SELECT name,hospitalID,currentAvgRating,city,
              @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
       FROM hospitals h, ( SELECT @curRank := 0) r 
       ORDER BY currentAvgRating DESC
      ) toplist 
WHERE toplist.hospitalID = @hospitalID 
  and city = @city
```

This query I am using to find the rank of particular item & it is working properly. But while runining in program I get Fatal errors of Parameter '@curRank' must be defined. But that is mysql syntax then how can I get it's parameters?

UPDATE

```
string str = "SELECT name, hospitalID, currentAvgRating, rank FROM (SELECT name,hospitalID,currentAvgRating,city,@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM hospitals h, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY currentAvgRating DESC) toplist WHERE toplist.hospitalID = @hospitalID and city = @city";
con.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hospitalID", generalID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", cityName.Text);
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
con.Close();
```

Comment: Why don't you show the C# code that call this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the rank for a particular hospital/city pair without a rank.  Here is a close approximation to your query:

```
select count(*) + 1 as ranking
from hospitals h cross join
     (select h.currentAvgRating
      from hospitals h
      where h.hospitalID = @hospitalID and h.city = @city
     ) hh
where h.currentAvgRating > hh.currentAvgRating;
```

Unlike your code, this gives all hospitals with the same rating, the same ranking.

If you don't want to change the code, then refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524632/how-can-i-use-a-mysql-user-defined-variable-in-a-net-mysqlcommand).  Actually, I'll quote the relevant part:

> I have to add
>
> ```
> ;Allow User Variables=True
> ```
>
> to the connection string

Comment: Thanks. But my sql query is working properly as I want. Anyways adding Allow User Variables=True solved my problem so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is correct I think there are conflect with C# command parameter and mySQL parameter

try this modification of SQL code like this

```
SELECT name, hospitalID, currentAvgRating, rank 
FROM ( SELECT name,hospitalID,currentAvgRating,city,
              @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
       FROM hospitals h, ( SELECT @curRank := 0) r 
       ORDER BY currentAvgRating DESC
      ) toplist 
WHERE toplist.hospitalID = ?hospitalID 
  and city = ?city
```

you c# like this

```
   string str = <Example Above>;
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?hospitalID", generalID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?city", cityName.Text);
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt); 
    con.Close();
```

Just changeing the C# command parameter using ? than using @