# Entity Framework : Set MySQL custom environment variables

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, environment-variables, entity-framework-5, silverlight-5.0

I have an issue with Entity Framework 5.0. I'm working with Silverlight 5 and MySQL 5.6 too.

**I need to set an environment MySQL variable before each connexion to the MySQL server.**

E.g

> SET @my_var = 'test';

Under Mysql I don't have any issues.

The following raises an **EntityFrameworkException** (syntax error near '@').

```
this.ObjectContext.CreateQuery<object>(" SET @my_var = 'test' ");
```

OR

```
this.ObjectContext.CreateQuery<object>(" CALL set_my_var('test') ");
```

This last method raises a MySQLException saying that a DataReader is already open and need to be closed.

```
this.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<object>(" CALL set_my_var('test') ", null);
```

I also tried to set a MySQL system environment (no '@') with the same result every time.

Any help will be much appreciated !
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your statement is not a query (i.e. does not return any result) you should use `ExecuteStoreCommand`. Something like this should work:

```
ctx.ExecuteStoreCommand("SET @my_var = 'test'")
```

Comment: Hello. 

Thank you for your answer. 

I had tried this method too but MySQL raises an Exception : `@my_var must be defined`. 

I can't figure out how to escape the '@' character. 

I've also tried using a stored procedure setting this variable. No Exception. But it seems that the variable is never set. 
Should I open manually the connexion to the MySQL server in my context ?
I've read in this article that Entity Framework opens and closes connexions as many times as necessary : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896325%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Do you think that executing this method Entity Framework opens a connexion just for this command ?

I tried to do so. I added the connexion instruction into the Initialize method (overriden).
I tried to put this instruction into the "Insert" method I'm using but the variable is not. 
No changes for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I tried so many things that I misspelled my variable in my code. 
So the following finaly worked : `ctx.ExecuteStoreCommand("SET @my_var = 'test'");`

I decided to leave the instruction in the method `Initialize` of my domain service. This method is inherited of the `LinqToEntitiesDomainService` class.

**But you need to set `Allow User Variables=True` in your MySQL connection string**
(ref : [Is it possible to use a MySql User Defined Variable in a .NET MySqlCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958953/is-it-possible-to-use-a-mysql-user-defined-variable-in-a-net-mysqlcommand))

You simply need to use a recent version of the MySQL Connector because older versions use the '@' mark to define SQL parameters so it could conflict with custom variables. Now it uses the '?' mark : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html

My library was already up to date (6.6.5).

Thank you for the help !