# Declare SQL Server not working

Tags: c#, razor, sql-server-ce

I am using razor with C# and I need to declare a variable in SQL but it will not work.

```
insert_data = db.Query("DECLARE @myid INT");
```

I get the following error

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = DECLARE ]

EDIT:

I am trying to put data into one table, then get its unique ID and insert it into another.

```
insert_data = db.Query("INSERT INTO sorted (sorted_words) SELECT '" + sorted_word + "' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT sorted_words FROM sorted WHERE sorted_words = '" + sorted_word + "')");
insert_data = db.Query("DECLARE @myid BIGINT");
insert_data = db.Query("SET @myid = scope_identity()");
insert_data = db.Query("INSERT INTO words (words, sorted_id) SELECT '" + word + "', @myid WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT words FROM words WHERE words = '" + word + "')");
```

Comment: Mmn, where are you using Razor here?

Comment: `@myid` is not razor, its a sql variable

Comment: This isn't going to work.  Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Compact parameters are not declared in the same way as with SQL Server. When working with the Database helper, you should name your parameters `@0`, `@1`, `@2` etc, incrementing by 1 each time. Also, the `Database.Query` method is for selecting multiple rows of data. You should use `Execute` for inserts and `GetLastInsertId` for getting the most recent row's identity value:

```
db.Execute("INSERT INTO sorted (sorted_words) SELECT @0 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT sorted_words FROM sorted WHERE sorted_words = @0)", sorted_word);
var id = (int)db.GetLastInsertId();
db.Execute("INSERT INTO words (words, sorted_id) SELECT @0, @1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT words FROM words WHERE words = @0)", word, id);
```

Read more about working with data in Razor web pages here: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data

Answer (score 1):

Try the ExecuteStoreCommand instead of using Query

Refrence:
[Entity Framework : Set MySQL custom environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766530/entity-framework-set-mysql-custom-environment-variables)

Comment: Im connecting with simply 
'var db = Database.Open("database_name");'
where would I set that? Also i am using SQL Server compact 4.0

Comment: woopps my bad... thought you where using MySQL....
Are you using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write a stored procedure with all statements inside and execute this stored procedure from your code. This will be much easier to manage.