# query works in MySql editor but not from application

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a query that works in the mysql editor, but not from c# in VS. Other queries to this database do work with no problems. Here is the code:

```
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(Reusables.cstring);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SET @var := (SELECT idPatients FROM appointments); SELECT * FROM patients WHERE idPatients = @var";
            con.Open();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            Reusables.closeConnection(con);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
```

It throws "Fatal error has occurred during command execution".

I've stepped through the code to no avail. I put the query to a message box just to make sure its ok. I've specified the database in the query. As you can see, I have also tried opening a connection before calling the da.Fill() method, which as I understand it is not normally necessary. I am not really sure where to go from here. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure its allowed to have 2 statements in one command?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to add `;Allow User Variables=True` to the connection string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5530620/208067