# MySQL56 - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE - {"Parameter '@url_hash' must be defined."} c#

Tags: c#, mysql

When I run the following MySQL query using the MySQL connector, in c#, using ExecuteNonQuery(),  I get a fatal error:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '//Path hidden//' 
INTO TABLE unvisted_urls 
   FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ',' 
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
(@url_hash, url,link_name)  
SET url_md5=UNHEX(@url_hash);
```

The error I get is:

```
{"Parameter '@url_hash' must be defined."}
```

If I run the same query in SQLWorkbench56,  I don't get any errors and the data is imported correctly.

The problem was introduced after including @url_hash parameter.  Have I got the syntax correct or am I missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after some further research I found that the following question answered my problem:

[Is it possible to use a MySql User Defined Variable in a .NET MySqlCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958953/is-it-possible-to-use-a-mysql-user-defined-variable-in-a-net-mysqlcommand)

The problem seems to be related to needing to set "Allow User Variables=True" as part of your connection string after setting the password, server database etc.

The original source for the solution can be found in this [Blog](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2009/05/mysqldatamysqlclientmysqlexception-parameter-id-must-be-defined.html).

I've answered my own question to try and help other users who come across this obscure issue.