# Ignoring @symbol when uploading create procedure command to mysql via C#

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql.data

I created a program in C# to copy a MySql database structure and procedures to a newly created database. Then upload the new data to it. The problem it fails to upload procedures that include the '@' symbol in them, example:

```
SET @SEARCH := CONCAT( _SEARCH , '%');
```

The code I use to retrieve the procedures is:

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT CONCAT( 'CREATE PROCEDURE ', ISR.ROUTINE_NAME, '(', CASE WHEN ISP.PARAMETER_NAME IS NOT NULL THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(ISP.PARAMETER_MODE, ' ', ISP.PARAMETER_NAME, ' ', ISP.DTD_IDENTIFIER)) ELSE '' END, ')\n', ISR.ROUTINE_DEFINITION) AS Create_Procedure FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES ISR LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS ISP ON ISR.ROUTINE_SCHEMA = ISP.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA AND ISR.ROUTINE_NAME = ISP.SPECIFIC_NAME AND ISR.ROUTINE_TYPE = ISP.ROUTINE_TYPE WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = '" + Program.RemoteSource + "' GROUP BY ISR.ROUTINE_NAME;", remote);
using (MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
      while (dataReader.Read())
           {
             createProcedures.Add(dataReader.GetString(0));
           }
    };
```

and the following uploads the new create procedure statements to the new database:

```
counter = 0;
foreach (string procedure in createProcedures)
   {
     try
        {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(@procedure, remote);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            counter++;
            Console.Write("\rProcedures Created: " + counter + " of " + createProcedures.Count);
         }
     catch (MySqlException ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
         }
    }
```

and the error:

```
Error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x800040005): 
Fatal error encountered during command execution.  ---> 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x800040005): 
   Parameter '@SEARCH' must be defined.
```

How would I go about so that MySql.Data ignores the @ symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by adding `;Allow User Variables=True` to the connection string.

[Is it possible to use a MySql User Defined Variable in a .NET MySqlCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958953/is-it-possible-to-use-a-mysql-user-defined-variable-in-a-net-mysqlcommand?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

how about using parameters, like this:

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT CONCAT( 'CREATE PROCEDURE ', ISR.ROUTINE_NAME, '(', CASE WHEN ISP.PARAMETER_NAME IS NOT NULL THEN GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(ISP.PARAMETER_MODE, ' ',ISP.PARAMETER_NAME, ' ', ISP.DTD_IDENTIFIER)) ELSE '' END, ')\n', ISR.ROUTINE_DEFINITION) AS Create_Procedure FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES ISR LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS ISP ON ISR.ROUTINE_SCHEMA = ISP.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA AND ISR.ROUTINE_NAME = ISP.SPECIFIC_NAME AND ISR.ROUTINE_TYPE = ISP.ROUTINE_TYPE WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = @routine_schema GROUP BY ISR.ROUTINE_NAME;", remote);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@routine_schema", Program.RemoteSource);
    using (MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
          while (dataReader.Read())
               {
                 createProcedures.Add(dataReader.GetString(0));
               }
        };
```

Comment: There was no issue in that fragment of code, although I am normally a proponent of parameters. They weren't necessary in this instance were I would be the sole provider of that input, and the input itself is a database name so it shouldn't cause any errors in that query.