# use of regex in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I have query as shown below.

```
SELECT 
  myWord, 
  LEAST (
    if (Locate('0',myWord) >0,Locate('0',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('1',myWord) >0,Locate('1',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('2',myWord) >0,Locate('2',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('3',myWord) >0,Locate('3',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('4',myWord) >0,Locate('4',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('5',myWord) >0,Locate('5',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('6',myWord) >0,Locate('6',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('7',myWord) >0,Locate('7',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('8',myWord) >0,Locate('8',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('9',myWord) >0,Locate('9',myWord),999)
  ) as myPos
FROM myTable;
```

Using this query, I am finding the ***position of first integer in a string***.

### My Question Is

Using `regex` how can I eliminate those 10 lines that I have as shown below.

```
    if (Locate('0',myWord) >0,Locate('0',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('1',myWord) >0,Locate('1',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('2',myWord) >0,Locate('2',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('3',myWord) >0,Locate('3',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('4',myWord) >0,Locate('4',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('5',myWord) >0,Locate('5',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('6',myWord) >0,Locate('6',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('7',myWord) >0,Locate('7',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('8',myWord) >0,Locate('8',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('9',myWord) >0,Locate('9',myWord),999)
```

Any idea how to get this done?

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7bd4/15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [MySQL: Use REGEX to extract string (select REGEX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021507/mysql-use-regex-to-extract-string) and [the first result of google "mysql regex locate"](http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/using-a-regex-with-locate-588344.html). It seems that it is not possible to do that with a regular expression in mysql. Your solution is already a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

See this [User defined functions](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp).

You could use `REGEXP_INSTR?` from there to find the position of the numbers. (haven't tested it though.)