# Function to match a word in a string on a regular expression in MySQL

Tags: mysql, function

I need to do a MySQL select on field that contains multiple words separated by spaces.  The field looks something like this:  The `files` field contains an entry

```
"000asdf0515 000azxc0515 000apoi0515"
```

I need to select only one word matching a specific string, say `zxc`:

```
SELECT [whatever the query is]
    -> "000azxc0515"
```

I've been reading in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html for a solution that might work, but I so far don't see anything.

Is there a MySQL function that will do this or will I need to write my own?

Comment: so you need to split your field into more than one word and select the word that matches, is that right? Only spaces or any other symbol?

Comment: Exactly, only on spaces, and if I only get the first matching word, that is ok

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql: Use REGEX to extract string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021507/mysql-use-regex-to-extract-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql doesn't have regex tools for extracting sub-strings.
Not out of the box that is.
You need to get some extentions
https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg

This answer is based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18307241/788634