# Select a numbers only pattern from a text field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a column in my table that contains a text record of some large logging data.  These fields will have a 9 digit number (0-9) that starts with "3".

I simply want to **select** *only the pattern from this field*, not the whole field.  And to make things complicated, this pattern can be in a field *more than once*.

I think the `REGEX` I need is `3{8}[0-9]` this?

Is there a MySQL way only to do this?  I'd rather not have to write a php script to extract this data.

**EDIT:  It seems this is not possible with REGEX - can it be done with any of the other MySQL String functions?**

Comment: mysql regexes can only MATCH. they cannot do capturing or replacement.

Comment: so it is going to be `gobblygook four scoreandsevenyears847394057 agoour847394057fore fathers666brought uponthis continent`

Comment: @DrewPierce  Yes, it would look like that.  Its's actually logging from php's `print_r`.  And some of the values in the array's are the 9 digit numbers.

Comment: only 1 9digit number in there (on a given row shall we call it)?

Comment: [Here it is said you cannot do that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4021507/3832970).

Comment: @DrewPierce  No, it could be multiple.  But it looks like based on the link above this is not possible.

Comment: give an example of the `actual` data, not caring if there are more than one 9-digit number for any given row. it is important to know how the chunk begins and ends, that is, characters surrounding it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think MySQL or SQL in general is the right tool for text mining when dealing with non-normalized data.

Just

```
$ mysql_dump mydb mytable > dump.sql
```

your data into a file and then search for your pattern using

```
$ grep -o '3[0-9]\{8\}' dump.sql > numbers.txt
```

- `-o` tells grep to only display matched data.
- `3` and `[0-9]` are patterns to match `3` and `any number between 0-9`
- `\{8\}` is the escaped form of `{8}` telling grep that the previous pattern should match exactly 8 times

Final command from the discussion that also expects a non-numeric value after the 9 digits:

```
$ grep -Po '3[0-9]{8}(?=[^0-9])' dump.sql > numbers.txt
```

- uses perl regexp so no escaping is needed
- (?=...) is a lookahead that matches, but is not included in the result

Comment: any thoughts on how to deal with (exclude)  'eleven digits in a row starting with 3 all together31111111111yes together'   .... as it relates to his question

Comment: Excluding things in regular expressions is not that easy. A simple method would be to assume a 3, followed by 8 numbers, followed by something other than a number: `$ grep -o '3[0-9]\{8\}[^0-9]' dump.sql > numbers.txt`.

Comment: maybe i should rephrase. must start with 3, have 8 #'s following, but not a total of 9 or more following the 3, so that it eliminates unwanted junk

Comment: The previous solution should work. Beware that you'll get numbers containing that last non-digit because it is part of the pattern. To avoid this you can use a look-ahead, but you'll need the GNU grep, not the OS X grep (as I have). The command should look like `$ grep -Po '3[0-9]{8}(?=[^0-9])' dump.sql > numbers.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

> These fields will have a 9 digit number (0-9) that starts with "3".

Here's 3 cases to show the regexp and that it fulfills that specification:

```
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| '123456789' REGEXP '^3[0-9]{8}$' | '323456789' REGEXP '^3[0-9]{8}$' | 'junk-323456789' REGEXP '^3[0-9]{8}$' |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|                                0 |                                1 |                                     0 |
+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, SQL isn't especially suited to poking around inside of text. But you could do something as a stored function. Here's one that will grab the first positive integer out of a text value. That might be good enough if you don't have other numbers preceding the pattern you want; or you could modify it fairly easily to get the more precise pattern you want (for example, test each number it finds, and if it's not of the form you want, discard it and keep looking instead of exiting the loop):

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS firstNumber;

DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION firstNumber(s TEXT)
    RETURNS INTEGER
    COMMENT 'Returns the first integer found in a string'
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN

    DECLARE token TEXT DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE len INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE ind INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE thisChar CHAR(1) DEFAULT ' ';

    SET len = CHAR_LENGTH(s);
    SET ind = 1;
    WHILE ind <= len DO
        SET thisChar = SUBSTRING(s, ind, 1);
        IF (ORD(thisChar) >= 48 AND ORD(thisChar) <= 57) THEN
            SET token = CONCAT(token, thisChar);
        ELSEIF token <> '' THEN
            -- Could add extra pattern check here
            SET ind = len + 1;
        END IF;
        SET ind = ind + 1;
    END WHILE;

    IF token = '' THEN
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;

    RETURN token;

    END //
DELIMITER ;
```