# Extracting matches of REGEXP in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a table of tweets stored in the `body` field of the table. I run the following SQL query to check whether the tweet has an `@mention`:

```
SELECT username, created, body FROM mytable WHERE body REGEXP '@([a-zA-Z0-9\_\.]+)' ;
```

It works, and it gets me the rows that match the `REGEXP`.  Is it possible to just return the `@mentions` in the body rather than the entire body (same as the python `re.findall()` function?  The table is big and doing analysis on all of it is taking too long, and all I really need are the `@mentions` from each `body` field.

Comment: This is similiar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021507/mysql-use-regex-to-extract-string.

Comment: do you need to count the occurrences of `@mention` in each row?

Comment: No, I just need the name(s) of the `@mention` in each row

Comment: There is no simple way to extract a part of `body` based on a regexp.