# Mysql REGEX occurence and extraction in string

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a table `MY_TBL` with a varchar field `MY_FLD`. I need to find rows where `MY_FLD` contains a number followed by a hyphen followed by a number (typically a range).

The following lines should be selected:

```
fffff 1-5 fdsfdsfds
1-5 fdsfdsfds 
aaaa 10-23
1-50 fdsfdsfds
```

and these should not:

```
-5 dsgdgf
10- rere
-15
10 -23
10- 23
```

The regex for the number-hyphen-number pattern is `\d+\-\d+`.

How do I use it in a MySql statement? Is it possible to extract the pattern into a separate string?

```
fffff 1-5 fdsfdsfds  ->  1-5
1-5 fdsfdsfds  ->  1-5
aaaa 10-23  ->  10-23
1-50 fdsfdsfds  ->  1-50
```

Comment: You will need to return the full row then pull the value with a regex in PHP. Here's a thread on extracting with mysql, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021507/mysql-use-regex-to-extract-string-select-regex, one of the answers has a tool you could install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this to retrieve the matching rows:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TBL WHERE MY_FLD REGEXP '[0-9]+-[0-9]+'
```

No need to escape the `-` and to match a digit, use `[0-9]` bracket expression.

There is no easy, built-in way to extract the regex matches in MySQL though.