# Select one row without duplicate entries on regex based

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

My info table has the following columns:

id, comment, status

I want to select all comment from info, and am using the following query :

```
SELECT name FROM info WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id
```

the comment columns has the following content :

id 1 : hello world 2010

id 2 : hello the world 2010

id 3 : hello iam in 2010

id 4 : hello 2020 
 ...

I want to echo all the entries filtred by number (regex number 0-9 4 digit) without duplicates. 
example for output :
id 1 : 2010
id 4 : 2020
Saying: under columns "comment" we have inserted more than 100 row in different value.

Comment: Is your 4 digit no. will always be at the end of string ?

Comment: it can not be at the beginning or at the end or half

Comment: `it can not be at the beginning or at the end or half`.  So NOT at the beginning, NOT at the end, NOT in the middle?  Where can it be then?

Answer (score 1):

You really need a function which will extract the year based on a regular expression, like PHP's `preg_match()`. Michael Packer's answer does this using Oracle. However, [MySQL lacks a built-in function for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4021872/5651536); its regex functions only allow for saying **if** something matches, not **extraction** of the matches.

There might be a better solution specific to your use-case, depending on your data format. For example, if the year contains the only numbers in the column, etc.

Alternatively, you could do the processing in PHP. To allow future queries to do this, you could have PHP extract the year value from the text and store it in a separate column. SELECT queries could then GROUP BY that column.