# Error in mysql bigint variable declaration inside custom nextval function

Tags: mysql, sql, database, t-sql

I forget put delimiter directive, some semicolon and was using tsl syntax like [select variable = field] that is not valid in mysql.
Mysql error when you use tsl syntax is [not allowed to return a result set from a function] and dont help much.
@AndreKR point all of it to me, thanks.
Im using mysqlworkbench 5.2.30 CE.
The work function become:

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION nextval (seq_name varchar(100))  
  RETURNS bigint(20)  
    READS SQL DATA  
  NOT DETERMINISTIC  
    BEGIN  
     DECLARE workval bigint(20);  
     SELECT count(1) into workval  
        FROM tip_sequence  
        WHERE sequencename = seq_name;  
     IF workval <> 1 THEN  
        DELETE  
            FROM tip_sequence  
            WHERE sequencename = seq_name;  
        INSERT  
            INTO tip_sequence (sequencename, sequenceval, sequencestep)  
            VALUES (seq_name, 1, 1);  
     END IF;
     SELECT sequenceval into workval  
        FROM tip_sequence  
        WHERE sequencename = seq_name;  
     UPDATE tip_sequence  
        SET sequenceval = sequenceval + sequencestep  
        WHERE sequencename = seq_name;  
     RETURN workval;
    END//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: @Mitch Wheat The version is [Server version: 5.1.53-community MySQL Community Server (GPL)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `DECLARE workval bigint(20);` line is the first one with a semicolon at the end, I suspect you forgot to change the delimiter before inputting the function code (though this depends on the client you're using).

Try changing your code to:

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE FUNCTION nextval (seq_name varchar(100))  

...

END#
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its solve that problem. I have a new problem now and edited question with details. I did the correction you pointed to me too.

Comment: Please open a new question if you have another problem. (To which the solution has something to do with the word "into", I guess.)

Comment: Im sory, i tried declare another variable do transfer value and return but its dont work, there is the ask with detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073404/function-complain-about-not-allowed-to-return-a-result-set-from-a-function-whe