# What's wrong with creating sequence id hibernate generator?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, sequence

I want to use sequence id generator,that will work in all databases.So i was seacrhing for an answer and found that [blog](http://www.javaplex.com/blog/how-to-achieve-database-auto-id-generation-portability-in-hibernate/comment-page-1/#comment-1592) and according to this next snippet must work:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="tablegenEmpl")    
    @GenericGenerator(name="tablegenEmpl",strategy="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters={
                @Parameter(name="sequence_name",value="ID_SEQ"),
                @Parameter(name="optimizer",    value="hilo"),
                @Parameter(name="initial_value",value="2100"),
                @Parameter(name="increment_size",value="1")
            })
    @Column(name="ID",unique=true,nullable=false)
    private Long id;
....
```

And my SQL script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employees`;
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `FIRSTNAME` varchar(255)  DEFAULT NULL,
  `LASTNAME` varchar(255)  DEFAULT NULL,
  `SALARY` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `BIRTHDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACTIVE` boolean DEFAULT NULL,
  `DEPARTAMENTID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

But i got an exception.What cause that?:

```
10:21:00,513 ERROR TableStructure:114 - could not read a hi value
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'employ.id_seq' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2275)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.doWorkInCurrentTransaction(TableStructure.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TransactionHelper$1Work.doWork(TransactionHelper.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.Isolater$JdbcDelegate.delegateWork(Isolater.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.Isolater.doIsolatedWork(Isolater.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TransactionHelper.doWorkInNewTransaction(TransactionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.OptimizerFactory$HiLoOptimizer.generate(OptimizerFactory.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:507)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cascadeOnUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:507)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:495)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$16.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:740)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(HibernateTemplate.java:737)
    at com.mycompany.employeers.dao.EmployeesDAOImpl.saveDepartament(EmployeesDAOImpl.java:63)
    at com.mycompany.employees.dao.BaseDaoTest.testGetEmployeesFromDepartament(BaseDaoTest.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:52)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
enter code here
```

Comment: Because MySQL does not support sequences.

@see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304461/generate-an-integer-sequence-in-mysql

Comment: But org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator on databases which support SEQUENCES will in fact use a SEQUNCE as the value generator; for those database which do not support SEQUENCES, it will instead use a single-row table as the value generator, but with the same exact charecteristics as a SEQUENCE value generator (namely it deals with the sequence table in a separate transaction at all times)”

Comment: [http://in.relation.to/2082.lace] - look at this..

Comment: and this table does not exist: Table 'employ.id_seq' doesn't exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need another table `id_seq` with one column `next_val`. You should ideally name the seq table after the entity name - something like `employee_sequence` and then specify that in the sequence_name parameter.

Comment: Thanks,Gkamal. I did as you said, but there is another error:ERROR TableStructure:107 - could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table: employee_sequence. What can i do with this?

Comment: I think you need to insert one row into the table with the initial value of the next_val. I think mysql ids start from 1, so setting it to 1 should work.

Comment: Thanks again Gkamal!You helped me.Yes the reason was with initial value.

Comment: @gkamal I have a similar question.  Are you willing to help me with it?  Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252541/generatedvalue-polymorphic-abstract-superclass-over-mysql/25268134#25268134