# Mysql Count 1 by 1

Tags: mysql

$sql=sprintf("SELECT * FROM  `stitch`);

This my array.

```
       [stitch] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 7, 
                                 [name] => Sew buttonhole to front fly
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 8,
                                [name] => Sleeve hem    
                            )
                     )                
                )
```

I need this result

```
               [stitch] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 7,
                                [name] => Sew buttonhole to front fly  
                                [number_stitch] => 1
                     )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 8,
                                [name] => Sleeve hem 
                                [number_stitch] => 2                             
                            )
                     )                
                )
```

how i do these [number_stitch] ?

Comment: Apparently `number_stitch` is not part of the `stitch` table.

Comment: It does not, number_stitch is just a sequence of stitch count

Comment: Why would you `sprintf` on a string with nothing to interpolate? Cargo-cult programming?

Comment: @RogérioBispoVilaNova If you're using PHP, you shouldn't need that.

Comment: So I put the select for you to see the issue, but what matters is the result of the option array below it worked thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select s.*, @rowcount:=@rowcount+1 ‘number_stitch’ from stitch s, (SELECT @rowcount:=0) r order by id;
```

Comment: FYI, this answer corresponds with the highest voted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304461/generate-an-integer-sequence-in-mysql

Comment: Oh sorry, did not know how to find this type of question