# How to SELECT and move forward by 7 DAYS MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Can somebody please explain how I would `SELECT` a DATE and move forward in intervals of `7 DAYS` given a date range in a `WHERE` clause?

Here's my example SQL:

```
SELECT DATE(*TIMESTAMP*) + (DATE_ADD(DATE(*TIMESTAMP*), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) as `interval`
WHERE digital_lead.received <= '2014-12-16 08:37:00' AND
digital_lead.received >= '2014-11-14 08:37:00'
```

So the expected output would appear like

```
interval 
2014-11-14
2014-11-21
2014-11-28
2014-12-05
```

The `SELECT` statement moves forward `7 DAYS` given the date range in the `WHERE` clause.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2652051/2307520 from similar question, I were able to do this:

```
select date_add('2014-11-14 08:37:00', INTERVAL (row) DAY) FROM
(
SELECT @row := @row + 7 as row FROM 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t,
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2, 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t3, 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t4, 
(SELECT @row:=-7) q
WHERE @row<=DATEDIFF('2014-12-16 08:37:00' , '2014-11-14 08:37:00')
) z
```

Comment: How would I include the start date in the results? As this begins from the 21st? Thanks

Comment: updated my answer ; just modify these two (three actually, start date is shown twince) timestamps.

Comment: It's still starting from the 21st ... ?