# How to find irregular increasements on mySQL

Tags: mysql, select, gaps-and-islands

My Table:

```
id         value
1          25
2          96
5          47
6          41
9          78
10         23
```

How to find irregular increasements(or not existence rows) like following:

**Result:** 3, 4, 7, 8

I dont want to read each one because of having 50k rows. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: @Jens I need to check every day missing data and i have to find them and save into db.

Comment: One thing I can suggest is to generate a sequence and do outer join against your table. The missing values will have a *null* which indicates your missing ID.

Comment: @JohnWoo Yes yes yes.. I can join another table with outer. Thanks, i'm trying now..

Comment: @bora, was my answer a solution or useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

## Simple approach

Ingredients:

- Generator table
- outer join

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b874a/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t ( id int, value int );
insert into t values ( 1, 12 );
insert into t values ( 3, 12 );
insert into t values ( 7, 12 );
insert into t values ( 9, 12 );
```

**Query 1**:

```
select generator.row
from t right outer join
( 
  SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row FROM 
  (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t,
  (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2, 
  (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t3, 
  (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t4, 
  (SELECT @row:=0) t5
) generator
on generator.row = t.id
where t.id is null and generator.row < ( select max( t.id) from t )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b874a/4/0)**:

```
| row |
|-----|
|   2 |
|   4 |
|   5 |
|   6 |
|   8 |
```

## Complex approach

If you need your gap limits, do you need some ingredients:

- MySQL Variables
- [Generator table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2652051/842935) with at least your max id

[Here your query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d1a0/16)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t ( id int, value int );
insert into t values ( 1, 12 );
insert into t values ( 3, 12 );
insert into t values ( 7, 12 );
insert into t values ( 9, 12 );
```

**The query**:

```
select generator.row, rFrom, rTo
from (
  SELECT @r := @r + 1 as r, 
         case 
            when @r < t.id then @r
            else Null
         end as rFrom,
         case 
            when @r < t.id then t.id - 1
            else Null
         end as rTo,
         @r := t.id 
  FROM t , (SELECT @r:=0) r
) gaps inner join
( 
  SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row FROM 
  (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t,
  (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2, 
  (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t3, 
  (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t4, 
  (SELECT @row:=0) t5
) generator
on generator.row between gaps.rFrom and gaps.rTo
where rFrom is not null
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d1a0/16/0)**:

```
| row | rFrom | rTo |
|-----|-------|-----|
|   2 |     2 |   2 |
|   4 |     4 |   6 |
|   5 |     4 |   6 |
|   6 |     4 |   6 |
|   8 |     8 |   8 |
```

First subquery looks for gaps intervals, second one is a generator to generate missing ids. Be free to execute both queries one by one to understand it.