# MySQL Fill in missing dates between two dates for a given status

Tags: mysql, date

I have a data set of projects.  The projects change status from beginning to end, and the date of the status change is logged in a table (table is named "events" - not my choice).  Would look like this (simplified):

```
Date        Status
2015-06-01  Start
2015-06-03  Stage 2
2015-06-07  Stage 3
```

In any given date range (to be determined dynamically) I want to be able to see which projects are at which status.  However, using BETWEEN or other query against the data will only pull those projects whose status *changed* during that period, not the ones that are still at a given status.

I've currently created a very clunky solution in Excel which copies rows into new rows between status change dates, like so:

```
Date          Status  
2015-06-01    Project start
2015-06-02    Project start (copied)
2015-06-03    Stage 2 
2015-06-04    Stage 2 (copied)
2015-06-05    Stage 2 (copied)
2015-06-06    Stage 2 (copied)
2015-06-07    Stage 3
```

This solution allows me to query the status for the project on, say, 2015-06-06 and see that it is still at Stage 2.

Is there some way I can use mySql to pull this same data, but as output to a query?  I've heard some suggest to use a Calendar table, but I'm not sure how that would work.  I've also seen someone recommend a Cross Join, but again, I couldn't understand from the description how that would work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**plan**

> - create calendar table by cross joining digits and date_add over calendar period..
> - join your data to calendar source with date <= calendar date
> - take max of date <= calendar date
> - join back to original data source to get status

**setup**

```
drop table if exists calendar_t;
CREATE TABLE calendar_t (
  id integer primary key auto_increment not null,
  `date` date not null,
  day varchar(9) not null,
  month varchar(13) not null,
  `year` integer not null
);

drop view if exists digits_v;
create view digits_v
as
select 0 as n
union all
select 1
union all
select 2
union all
select 3
union all
select 4
union all
select 5
union all
select 6
union all
select 7
union all
select 8
union all
select 9
;

insert into calendar_t
( `date`, day, month, `year` )
select 
date_add('2015-01-01', interval 100*a2.n + 10*a1.n + a0.n day) as `date`,
dayname(date_add('2015-01-01', interval 100*a2.n + 10*a1.n + a0.n day)) as day,
monthname(date_add('2015-01-01', interval 100*a2.n + 10*a1.n + a0.n day)) as month,
year(date_add('2015-01-01', interval 100*a2.n + 10*a1.n + a0.n day)) as `year`
from
digits_v a2
cross join digits_v a1
cross join digits_v a0
order by date_add('2015-01-01', interval 100*a2.n + 10*a1.n + a0.n day)
;

drop table if exists example;
create table example
(
  `date` date not null,
  status varchar(23) not null
);

insert into example
( `date`, status )
values
( '2015-06-01',  'Start'   ),
( '2015-06-03',  'Stage 2' ),
( '2015-06-07',  'Stage 3' )
;
```

**query**

```
select cal_date, mdate, ex2.status
from
(
select cal_date, max(ex_date) as mdate
from
(
select cal.`date` as cal_date, ex.`date` as ex_date
from calendar_t cal
inner join example ex
on ex.`date` <= cal.`date`
) maxs
group by cal_date
) m2
inner join example ex2
on m2.mdate = ex2.`date`
-- pick a reasonable end date for filtering..
where cal_date <= date('2015-06-15')
order by cal_date
;
```

**output**

```
+------------------------+------------------------+---------+
|        cal_date        |         mdate          | status  |
+------------------------+------------------------+---------+
| June, 01 2015 00:00:00 | June, 01 2015 00:00:00 | Start   |
| June, 02 2015 00:00:00 | June, 01 2015 00:00:00 | Start   |
| June, 03 2015 00:00:00 | June, 03 2015 00:00:00 | Stage 2 |
| June, 04 2015 00:00:00 | June, 03 2015 00:00:00 | Stage 2 |
| June, 05 2015 00:00:00 | June, 03 2015 00:00:00 | Stage 2 |
| June, 06 2015 00:00:00 | June, 03 2015 00:00:00 | Stage 2 |
| June, 07 2015 00:00:00 | June, 07 2015 00:00:00 | Stage 3 |
| June, 08 2015 00:00:00 | June, 07 2015 00:00:00 | Stage 3 |
| June, 09 2015 00:00:00 | June, 07 2015 00:00:00 | Stage 3 |
| June, 10 2015 00:00:00 | June, 07 2015 00:00:00 | Stage 3 |
| June, 11 2015 00:00:00 | June, 07 2015 00:00:00 | Stage 3 |
| June, 12 2015 00:00:00 | June, 07 2015 00:00:00 | Stage 3 |
| June, 13 2015 00:00:00 | June, 07 2015 00:00:00 | Stage 3 |
| June, 14 2015 00:00:00 | June, 07 2015 00:00:00 | Stage 3 |
| June, 15 2015 00:00:00 | June, 07 2015 00:00:00 | Stage 3 |
+------------------------+------------------------+---------+
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2206c/5)**

---

**reference**

- [SO mysql sequence generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304461/generate-an-integer-sequence-in-mysql#2652051)
- [sql cross join](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php)

Comment: Thanks, amdixon.  I'll give that a shot when I'm back in the office.  In the meantime, I'll work on figuring out what it means :)  I've never used Cross Joins before, and wondered what they were used for.  I think I'm about to find out.

Comment: cross join means take all combinations of records from left and right datasets. so if you cross join a dataset with 2 records with a dataset with 5 records, you end up with a dataset with 10 records. check out [cross join](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php). in this context its a way to generate a numeric sequence

Comment: @RyanVincent yes you can use this as a readily available datasource ( for sequence generation ) for calendar population. efficiency is probably not a concern, as the calendar load will only happen a maximum of once a year. just make sure there are no gaps in the id sequence..

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to create a table with all the dates. you could alter your table to give the start and end dates for each status and use a between statement.

or using your existing data.

using @datequery as the date you want to find out the status for.

```
Select top 1 Status from Events
where Date <= @datequery and Date 
order by Date desc
```

returns the most recent status change before the date you are querying.

```
@datequery = 2015-06-06

Status
Stage 2
```