# select range of dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

how can I select a list of dates in MySQL so even if there are no results for a specific date the date itself will appear?

I want something like:

```
select every_date,count(*) from my_table group by date,order by date;
```

that will generate:

```
20160110 5
20160109 0
20160108 7
20160107 1
```

Comment: see **[mysql-fill-in-missing-dates-between-two-dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545056/mysql-fill-in-missing-dates-between-two-dates-for-a-given-status/34545534)**

Comment: your question not clear

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide as much details as you can. It makes finding answer easier, for example could you please describe table "my_table" (what columns are there)? http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask