# Filling gaps between dates and stage for opportunity

Tags: mysql, date, cross-join

I am pretty new to MySQL and wanted to ask for help which would be much appreciated!

Let's have opp_history table like (plus its pk):

```
opp_id date_created stage                   
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-05  Qualification
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-06  Validating benefits
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-09  Offer
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-09  Validating benefits
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-10  Offer
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-15  Closed Lost
00658000009PIZHAA4  2016-11-04  Validating benefits
00658000009PIZHAA4  2016-11-04  Offer
00658000009PIZHAA4  2016-11-04  Qualification
00658000009PIZHAA4  2016-11-04  Offer
00658000009PIZHAA4  2016-11-10  Closed Lost
```

And what I would like to do is to fill in the gaps with dates between each stage with the previous stage value, so:

```
opp_id date_created stage                   
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-05  Qualification
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-06  Validating benefits
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-07  Validating benefits
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-08  Validating benefits
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-09  Offer
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-09  Validating benefits
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-10  Offer
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-11  Offer
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-12  Offer
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-13  Offer
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-14  Offer
00658000009Pa0gAAC  2016-11-15  Closed Lost
00658000009PIZHAA4  2016-11-04  Validating benefits
00658000009PIZHAA4  2016-11-04  Offer
00658000009PIZHAA4  2016-11-04  Qualification
00658000009PIZHAA4  2016-11-05  Offer
00658000009PIZHAA4  2016-11-06  Offer
00658000009PIZHAA4  2016-11-07  Offer
00658000009PIZHAA4  2016-11-08  Offer
00658000009PIZHAA4  2016-11-09  Offer
00658000009PIZHAA4  2016-11-10  Closed Lost
```

However even though I read this post: [MySQL Fill in missing dates between two dates for a given status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545056/mysql-fill-in-missing-dates-between-two-dates-for-a-given-status)
I am still struggling to apply the same logic cause the opp_id where the max date must be the max created date for each opp_id.

I already created the calendar dummy table and view as suggested there.

Thanks so much for your advises! 
Feel free to ask anything, Z.

Comment: You don't really need to 'store' this though, right?

Comment: My apologies, what do you mean by storing it? I need to create a table so I can count # days opportunity was in certain stage in some visualization tool - this is something what I don't want to do in MySQL so I can use dashboard filters in the viz. tool.

Comment: If it was me, I think I'd just do the whole thing in the viz. tool - although, in the absence of a PRIMARY KEY, you may struggle.

Comment: there is PK for sure, I just didn't include it in this example :-)