# SQL - group by value range between 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose we have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    id int primary key,
    from int, 
    to int
);

INSERT INTO a (id, from, to) VALUES (1, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO a (id, from, to) VALUES (2, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO a (id, from, to) VALUES (3, 2, 4);
```

I need to write a query, that will return:

```
+------------+---------+
|    id      |  value  |
+------------+---------+
|     1      |   1     |
|     1      |   2     |
|     1      |   3     |
|            |         |
|     2      |   1     |
|     2      |   2     |
|            |         |
|     3      |   2     |
|     3      |   3     |
|     3      |   4     |
+------------+---------+
```

The first column is `id` itself. The second column should contain all values between `from` and `to`, with step 1 between values.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the application layer if that's available (e.g. a bit of PHP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a table of numbers.  How you generate such a table depends on the database you are using.  But, for small numbers, you can do it manually:

```
select t.id, (t.from + n.n) as value
from t join
     (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
     ) n
     on t.from + n.n <= t.to;
```

Comment: I have very small numbers, so I will stick to your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @nickbusted If you need more rows you can use this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2652051/460557) to generate a larger set.