# Oracle has "all_objects" table. Does exist some similar large table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I would like to do something as:

```
SELECT ROWNUM FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE ROWNUM <= 100000
```

Which large table do we have in MysQL?

Comment: And for those unfamiliar with oracle what does this do?

Comment: I don't think MySQL has any table that has 100,000 rows by default.

Comment: Do you know a smaller table, @GordonLinoff? Which is the size?

Comment: It will just show all numbers between 1 and 100000, @P.Salmon.

Comment: In general you shouldn't count on the existence of a large table to get a sequence of numbers. In Oracle I'd usually use something like `SELECT LEVEL N FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10` to get numbers from 1 to 10. There are many other ways to accomplish this - see [this ORAFAQ article](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques) for examples. Also, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/904110/213136) for a MySQL solution. Best of luck.

Comment: I'm seeing the answer... How many rows does "some_table" have? It could be just 1 row, right? In this case, it will not work. But forget it. MySQL sucks...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.  Look at INFORMATION_SCHEMA, pick the largest table in there.

Documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html

<sub>But I must say that this is a very clunky way of producing a long sequence of numbers. There may be better ways, but you are not going to receive them with this question, because you have not really asked a question, you have asked an answer.  You might want to ask a question instead, beginning by explaining what it is that you want to achieve, instead of coming up with a wacky idea about how to achieve it, and asking how to implement your wacky idea.</sub>