# Updating to every number after column value, up to 9?

Tags: mysql, database

So I created a database table in MySQL that held permission rights for permissions and commands, the command rights started with the prefix `command_` in the column `permission_name` and then I have an extra column called `allowed_ranks`, which is a list of INT rank ID's that are required, split by a `,` character.

The issue is, the command ones were anything higher, and I've put 1 id in `allowed_ranks`, is there a way I can loop through all the ones with column starting with command_ and change the allowed_ranks that are just 1 ID to every number starting from that to 9? 9 is the maximum rank ID.

I've already done part of the query, I'm just not sure how to do the updating?

```
UPDATE permission_rights` SET `allowed_ranks` = '?' WHERE `permission_name` LIKE 'command_%';
```

How would I update it to every number after the columns value up to 9? So lets say I had this record... just a quick example to ensure you know what I mean.

```
 | permission_name | allowed_ids |
----------------------------------
 | command_hello   | 2
 | command_junk    | 5
 | command_delete  | 8 
 | command_update  | 1
```

Would become...

```
 | permission_name | allowed_ids |
----------------------------------
 | command_hello   | 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
 | command_junk    | 5,6,7,8,9
 | command_delete  | 8,9
 | command_update  | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: can you post you DB structure with sample data? it's not clear where the list of allowed_ids comes from

Answer (score 0):

The better approach would be to use a number generator (some method which will produce number from 1 to n), but general MySQL has no such capability.

If you use MariaDB you can use `seq_1_to_1000` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304461/generate-an-integer-sequence-in-mysql) in Answer by O.Jones.

However your use case seems to be simpler, since you said that the highest rank is 9, I would just use

```
update a 
set a.allowed_ids = RIGHT('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9',19-2*a.allowed_ids) 
where a.permission_name like 'command_%'
```