# Take count based on rage of date SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I have below mentioned sql query which gives me simple count as on that date or if i use `where` and `and` condition for date it gives me consolidated count between the date.

`select count(*) from A where date(date_1) = '2017-06-01';`

I want count for a range of date for separate count for each date.

`select count(*) from A where date(date_1) >= '2017-06-01' and date(date_1)<='2017-06-30';`

```
Desired output:

Date          Count

2017-06-01    25
2017-06-02    20
2017-06-03    15
-             -
-             -
2017-06-30    10
```

Comment: Tip of today: `GROUP BY`.

Comment: So true, jarlh :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following might work:

```
SELECT DATE(date_1), COUNT(*)
FROM A
GROUP BY DATE(date_1)
```

`COUNT`, being an [aggregate function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx), is often combined with the `GROUP BY` clause in order to get aggregate results per group (in this case, counts per date).

`WHERE` clauses can of course be added as desired, right before the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Dates missing in the table will be missing from the output

Comment: True, but for now it seems unclear whether this is a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to use `group by` clause like:

```
SELECT date(date_1),Count(*) as [Count]
FROM A
WHERE date(date_1) >= '2017-06-01' and date(date_1)<='2017-06-30'
GROUP BY date(date_1)
```

Comment: This won't indicate dates with missing data.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli Thanks...:)

Comment: Could use `between` to shorten `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution also reports days with no noted incidents. The example is devised for the month of February:

```
    SELECT (DATE'2018-01-31' + INTERVAL x.n DAY) dd
         , COALESCE(sqt.c, 0)                    incidents
      FROM (select 1 n union all select 2 n union all select 3 n union all select 4 n union all select 5 n union all select 6 n union all select 7 n union all select 8 n union all select 9 n union all select 10 n union all select 11 n union all select 12 n union all select 13 n union all select 14 n union all select 15 n union all select 16 n union all select 17 n union all select 18 n union all select 19 n union all select 20 n union all select 21 n union all select 22 n union all select 23 n union all select 24 n union all select 25 n union all select 26 n union all select 27 n union all select 28 n) x
 LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT date1    d
                     , count(*) c
                  FROM t
              GROUP BY date1
           ) sqt
        ON sqt.d = (DATE'2018-01-31' + INTERVAL x.n DAY)
         ;
```

The standalone demo can be viewed [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bccc5/5).

The sequence generator has been shamelessly adopted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307986/).