# Repeat row based on values in column

Tags: mysql, sql

Esteemed StackOverflow Community,

I have a table with the following data. I want to be able to produce `n` rows based on `5 - value in column E`. 
Also want to be able to make the value in column `F` zero, keeping the values for A, B, C, D intact.

I'm not in a position to create a temp table.

**INPUT**

`Table1`

```
A    B    C    D    E    F
AA   BB   CC   DD   1    100
AA   BB   CC   DD   3    200
AA   BB   CC   DD   5    300
EE   FF   GG   HH   1    600
```

`Table2`

```
key      desc
1        AABBCCDD
2        EEFFGGHHH
```

**OUTPUT**

```
A    B    C    D    E    F    key
AA   BB   CC   DD   1    100  1
AA   BB   CC   DD   3    200  1
AA   BB   CC   DD   5    300  1
AA   BB   CC   DD   2    0    1
AA   BB   CC   DD   4    0    1
EE   FF   GG   HH   1    600  2
EE   FF   GG   HH   2    0    2
EE   FF   GG   HH   3    0    2
EE   FF   GG   HH   4    0    2
EE   FF   GG   HH   5    0    2
```

My existing SQL looks like this.

```
SELECT A.*,B.key from table1 as A
JOIN table2 as B on concat(A.A,A.B,A.C) = B.desc;
```

Comment: Note that desc is a reserved word. Also, this kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: Can you kindly explain how you get values for Column F .What is the business rules

Comment: So you want to use (unseparated) values in table2 to connect to table1? How should MySQL know how the handle (parse) `AABBCCDD` into `AA`, `BB`, `CC`, `DD`.. Or is the possible data width within the table1 always 2 like in `CHAR(2)`?

Comment: There is no business rule for column `F`.

Comment: @Strawberry - the column in `table2` is called `key_desc`. My bad for making it not clear.

Comment: Fine. The other point stands.

Comment: @Strawberry - agree, but that's what i have to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to cross join to a list of numbers somehow.

One way to that is using a tally table with enough numbers.

Then join those numbers to all the unique A, B, C, D.
This will get a basis for all possible combinations.

Then LEFT JOIN the tables to that result.

Test on SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b0084/5)

```
SELECT 
 Abcd.A, Abcd.B, Abcd.C, Abcd.D, 
 Nums.n as E, 
 COALESCE(t1.F, 0) as F, 
 t2.`key`
FROM (
  SELECT MIN(E) AS MinE, MAX(E) AS MaxE, MAX(F) AS MaxF FROM Table1
) AS Limits
JOIN Nums ON n BETWEEN Limits.MinE AND Limits.MaxE
JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C, D FROM Table1
) AS Abcd
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON (t1.A, t1.B, t1.C, t1.D) = (Abcd.A, Abcd.B, Abcd.C, Abcd.D) AND t1.E = Nums.n
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t2.`desc` LIKE CONCAT(Abcd.A, Abcd.B, Abcd.C, Abcd.D, '%')
ORDER BY Abcd.A, Abcd.B, Abcd.C, Abcd.D, COALESCE(t1.F, Limits.MaxF), Nums.n;
```

Sample data used:

```
create table Table1 (A varchar(2), B varchar(2), C varchar(2), D varchar(2), E int, F int); 

create table Table2 (`key` int primary key auto_increment, `desc` varchar(30));

insert into Table1 (A, B, C, D, E, F) values
('AA','BB','CC','DD',1,100),
('AA','BB','CC','DD',3,200),
('AA','BB','CC','DD',5,300),
('EE','FF','GG','HH',1,600);

insert into Table2 (`desc`) values
('AABBCCDD'),
('EEFFGGHH');

 CREATE TABLE Nums (n int primary key);

 INSERT INTO Nums (n) VALUES
 (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);
```

Comment: this is brilliant, except that I cant create a table. Is there a version without creating the `nums` table?

Comment: @TydariusJaxson Well, if you're using MySql 8 then you could use a Recursive CTE I guess.  But in MySql 5.x you don't have CTE's.  But it's not the first time in SO that someone asked that. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304461/generate-an-integer-sequence-in-mysql) for example.  I find the `(select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3)` a bit wordy for my taste, but it works for a small list of numbers. But can you create a [TEMPORARY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) table?

Comment: I wouldn't mind doing the `Select 1 as n union select 2` to get the nums table. Question is, where would this go into your query?

Comment: @TydariusJaxson As a join on a sub-query to replace the join on Nums. `... JOIN (<the unioned selects>) AS Nums ON ...`