# How to put values coming from a loop into a table in SQL In C language

Tags: mysql, sql, c

I want to Put the values coming from the given loop in a table in sql. How to do the same..In C Language only

I can make Tables and store the fixed values in it, but want to know how to store in SQL tables if different values are coming from this loop.

```
printf("\nDestination IP Address: ");
for(i = 30; i<=32; i++)
{       
printf("%d", packet[i]);
printf(".");
}
```

I want the table to store the values coming from this loop in real-time and then show when asked.

Comment: How to store values in real time in sql table...please help in this only

Answer (score 0):

see the link you will find the solution

> [generate an integer sequence in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304461/generate-an-integer-sequence-in-mysql)